# How to check if libxml2 is initialized

Tags: c, multithreading, unix, libxml2

According to [this](http://xmlsoft.org/threads.html) document about multithreading, it is mandatory to call `xmlInitParser()` before using the library concurrently. Here's the problem. I coded a library(not an executable) using libxml2 and it should guarantee concurrency. So I decided to call the init function on my library's init function. However, [the document](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlInitParser) says the function is not reentrant. So it could be problematic if other libraries or the program linking my library calls the function beforehand.

I couldn't find a function or a way to check if the parser(or libxml2 should I say) is initialised. What should I do? Call the function regardless and hope for the best? I'm going to test if the function is reentrant after all, after I post this but that doesn't really tally.

For clarification, in summary:

- Is `xmlInitParser()` actually reentrant?
- Any way to check if libxml2 is initialised?
- (OR) How to safely use libxml2 concurrently under the premise that another software could be using it concurrently as well.

Comment: The mailing list didn't seem very active so I'm asking here.

Comment: can you call it in the main routine before any threads have been spawned?  That's what I recall doing when I used libxml2.

Comment: Nitpick: Even if it isn't reentrant, it still may be called several times in succession.

Comment: "Reentrant" doesn't mean what I thought it means. How ignorant I was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After looking at the sourcecode (taken from [here](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d5/d00/sdk_2lib_23rdparty_2libxml2_2parser_8c_source.html#l14942)) it seems possible to call the function multiple times:

```
static int xmlParserInitialized = 0;

void
xmlInitParser(void) {
    if (xmlParserInitialized != 0)
     return;

 #ifdef LIBXML_THREAD_ENABLED
     __xmlGlobalInitMutexLock();
     if (xmlParserInitialized == 0) {
 #endif
     /* ... the actual initialization ... */
     xmlParserInitialized = 1;
 #ifdef LIBXML_THREAD_ENABLED
     }
     __xmlGlobalInitMutexUnlock();
 #endif
 }
```

You are concerned about multiple other libraries calling `xmlInitParser()` concurrently. The System V ABI implies that libraries are loaded one after another (see the section "Initialization and Termination Functions").
[Assuming none of the other libraries creates threads (that call `xmlInitParser()`)] this means that you do not have to worry about it.

If you really want to be safe you should link libxml statically in your library, so you have your own private copy that other libraries cannot interfere with.

Comment: I didn't plan to call it concurrently, but still the function looks thread safe if the thread support is enabled. My question was more about philosophical than technical. Surely, the documentation is misleading. It's not commenting what it really does or whether it is safe to be called in certain way.