# libxml2.so Init/CleanupParser usage for multiple processes with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, shared-libraries, libxml2

I am using **libxml2** as a **shared library** from different paralelly running processes on an **arm/linux** environment. The offical examples are one-off processes where the handling of [`InitParser()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlInitParser) and [`CleanupParser()`](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCleanupParser) are trivial.

In a setup where multiple processes use libxml2 I am not sure how to use it.

```
proc1 -thread1-> work -> libxml2.so -> ...
      -thread2-> work -> ...
      -thread3-> work -> work -> libxml2.so -> work -> ...
proc2 -thread1-> wrapper.so -> libxml2.so -> work -> ...
      -thread2-> work -> ...
      -thread3-> wrapper.so -> libxml2.so -> ...
```

### Problems

- Being an embedded device, the processes run normally 'forever', so I cannot afford any memory-leak. (I test the code with unittest+valgrind and live-run+memory monitor).
- `InitParser()` is not reentrent, so as I understang the `InitParser()` => ... => `CleanupParser()` on a thread level is not ok? (e.g. proc1::thr1 vs. proc1::thr3)

  - **That is why I am thinking about a process level house-keeping.

    But would a `CleanupParser()` call in `proc1` interact with `proc2's` libxml2 calls?**
    (Is it "tunneled-through" the shared-lib?)

---

#### `InitParser()`

> Initialization function for the XML parser. This is **not reentrant**. Call once **before** processing in case of use in **multithreaded programs**

#### `CleanupParser()`

> it cleans up memory allocated by the library itself. It is a cleanup
>   function for the XML library. It tries to reclaim all related global
>   memory allocated for the library processing. It doesn't deallocate any
>   document related memory. One should call xmlCleanupParser() only when
>   **the process has finished** using the library and all XML/HTML documents
>   built with it. See also xmlInitParser() which has the opposite
>   function of preparing the library for operations. WARNING: if your
>   application is multithreaded or has plugin support calling this may
>   crash the application if another thread or a plugin is still using
>   libxml2

I guess, the question reveals my limited knowledge of the inner-workings of shared-libs... Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read this: http://xmlsoft.org/threads.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if libxml2 is initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41689764/how-to-check-if-libxml2-is-initialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nowadays, `xmlInitParser` is thread-safe. But libxml2 will designate the first thread that calls the function as "main thread" internally. It's best to call this function once from the main thread before spawning other threads, for example, at the beginning of `main`.

`xmlCleanupParser` must never be called if any thread of the process invokes any other libxml2 functions afterwards. So `xmlInitParser() ... xmlCleanupParser()` on a thread level is not OK. You normally don't have to call `xmlCleanupParser` at all, but you'll need it to avoid false positives when checking for memory leaks with tools like valgrind or ASan. In this case, it's best to call it right before the process exits, for example at the end of `main`. Nowadays, `xmlCleanupParser` will be called automatically when libxml2 is unloaded on most platforms.